# Get the succes login and being redirect with node js

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, authentication

I've been working on a node project and everything is new to me.

So far, scraping the internet I managed to get the user logged in, but now, I don't know hot to direct to the user page once the login process succed.

In the index.js I have:

```
const userService = require('./auth');

app.post('/login', function(req, res){

var userEmail = req.body.emailLogin;
var userPassword = req.body.passwordLogin;
console.log(userEmail, userPassword); //This log the email and the password

userService.loginUser(emailRegister, passwordRegister,

    function(error, authData) {

        if (error) {
            return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');

        } else {
            res.render('user');
        }
    });
});
```

and in the auth.js

```
function loginUser(email, password){
    console.log(email, password);
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(function(firebaseUser) {
           // Success
            console.log('Ok, lovelly I\'m logged');
            return firebaseUser
       })
      .catch(function(error) {
           // Error Handling
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log(errorCode); //auth/user-not-found
          console.log(errorMessage); //There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.

          return errorMessage
      });
}
```

how can I return the `firebaseUser` to the main function and be redirect to the user page?

Comment: What is emailRegister & passwordRegister where did it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written your code in pre-ES6 standards using concept of callbacks

```
const userService = require("./auth");

app.post("/login", function(req, res) {
  var userEmail = req.body.emailLogin;
  var userPassword = req.body.passwordLogin;
  console.log(userEmail, userPassword); //This log the email and the password

  userService.loginUser(
    userEmail,
    userPassword,

    function(error, authData) {
      if (error) {
        return res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");
      } else {
        res.render("user");
      }
    }
  );
});
```

But you forgot to include the callback argument in login user method and once login user method is successful call `callback(null, result)` and if its an error call `callback(error)`.

```
function loginUser(email, password, callback) {
      console.log(email, password);
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(function(firebaseUser) {
          // Success
          console.log("Ok, lovelly I'm logged");
          callback(null, firebaseUser);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          // Error Handling
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log(errorCode); //auth/user-not-found
          console.log(errorMessage); //There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.

          callback(error);
        });
    }
```

I have rewritten the code using latest standards using async/await which is much more cleaner and is shorter.

```
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
const userEmail = req.body.emailLogin,
    userPassword = req.body.passwordLogin;
  const user = await loginUser(userEmail, userPassword).catch(error => {
    return res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");
  });
  res.render("index.js", user);
});

const loginUser = async (email, password) => {
  try {
    const user = await firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```

There's a concept of promises which I am not gonna go into because async/await is a syntactic sugar of it. You can read about all of it on [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)  [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

Answer (score 1):

You are confused between callback and promise learn how to work with async operation

Your code would look like this

```
function loginUser(email, password){
console.log(email, password);
// return promise
return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function(firebaseUser) {
       // Success
        console.log('Ok, lovelly I\'m logged');
        return firebaseUser
   })
}
```

And controller would be

```
   const userService = require('./auth');

    app.post('/login', function (req, res) {

    var userEmail = req.body.emailLogin;
    var userPassword = req.body.passwordLogin;
    console.log(userEmail, userPassword); //This log the email and the password

    userService.loginUser(emailRegister, passwordRegister)
        .then(function () {
            res.render('user');
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // Error Handling
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log(errorCode); //auth/user-not-found
            console.log(errorMessage); //There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.
            return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
        })
```

Comment: hello, can you help me with this issue here? the code is similar. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55548093/10158519

Comment: and when I dont have res.render?